# How to prevent changing client code for achieving Azure SQL Server Sharding?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, sharding

I'm just wondering if there is a solution for implementing Azure Sql Server sharding in a way you don't have to change the client code. I found articles about the implementation but in all of them you need to create an extra abstraction and you need to store all the information about all of the shards.

For example for MongoDB you can solve this by introducing a load balancer and then the load balancer will redirect the client to the appropriate Shard.

Is that possible with Sql Server?

Comment: Did you try this document [Database shard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction)?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation but I didn't find option to solve this without changing the client which connects to the DB